# Control amount of memory in a thread C#

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, threadpool

Is it possible to control the amount of memory to be used in a method, if reaching a specific amount drops the thread?

I have a problem that occasionally generates memory leak, and if a leak occurs I want to bring down the thread.

This problem occurs from a third party component, until they fix it i wanted to have a solution.

Comment: I don't know if it is possible: what you ask for is relevant to the Kernel code that manage the CPU internals... So perhaps there is some WinAPI available. For example, in x64 every process has 2GB of virtual memory available. I don't know if moderns CPU allow to define thread graininess. Found that: http://content.atalasoft.com/atalasoft-blog/increasing-the-size-of-your-stack-net-memory-management-part-3

Comment: Short answer: no. Memory is not allocated per thread, it's per app-domain.  And, it's managed memory, so the garbage collector is in charge.  What do you mean by *"a problem that occasionally generates memory leak"*?  Do you feel like you are leaking managed memory?  Does the component you are talking about use "unmanaged" memory (through P/Invoke or COM)?

Comment: Found that: [Windows Thread Stack Size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/thread-stack-size) & [Pushing the Limits of Windows: Processes and Threads](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-blog-archive/pushing-the-limits-of-windows-processes-and-threads/ba-p/723824)

Comment: What's the issue you're trying to fix?

Comment: @Sean I'm trying to fix the upload file from Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob. If I send a very large file it starts to scale memory until it drops the machine.
In .net 2.2 all attempts drop, when using GC.Collect I can upload larger files up to 3MB without uploading the memory, when trying 9MB files it drops.
In 3.1 it occurs with a lower frequency. but when it comes to production, I can't risk letting the error occur.

Comment: In general, when you are using large files, you are better off trying to devise a streaming solution that doesn't require that you copy the file into managed memory (and sometimes copy it within the app) only to save it somewhere else.  This generally is a doable thing, but it requires study and a bit of an understanding about how the garbage collector works (in particular, understanding how the large object heap (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/large-object-heap) factors into things.  The obvious solution often fails.  This, btw, is not a memory leak

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: No. Memory belongs to the process (in general) or in .NET at least to the AppDomain. CPU time belongs to threads.

Long answers:

a) There is [ThreadLocalStorage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/thread-local-storage), which was made for storing stuff that relates to a thread. In .NET it's [`ThreadLocal<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadlocal-1?view=netcore-3.1). But since you can't modify the library, it will not make use of it.

b) If you implement your own memory management, you could potentially check on which thread memory is allocated. It [seems possible](https://blog.adamfurmanek.pl/2016/05/07/custom-memory-allocation-in-c-part-3/), but I would not recommend it.  That's more a thing for C and C++, where you could easily use a `#define` on `new` and `malloc()` to override how memory is allocated on the heap.

c) if your library is a native library (or a wrapper for a native library), also b) is useless, since memory allocations will take a diferent way.

Comment: Well, except for stack space and thread local storage.

Comment: @Blindy: yes and no :-) As long as one thread knows an address of another thread's stack, it will be able to access it. So it does not belong to one thread exclusively.